# TradingView Long or Short only signal

Tags: pine-script, trading, algorithmic-trading

I wanted to know if it is possible to make the strategy give a signal only for Long or Short? But this does not break the work of the strategy itself.

```
//@version=5
strategy("BarUpDn 2Strategy", overlay=true, default_qty_type = strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value = 10)
maxIdLossPcnt = input.float(1, "Max Intraday Loss(%)")
strategy.risk.max_intraday_loss(maxIdLossPcnt, strategy.percent_of_equity)
if (close > open and open > close[1])
    strategy.entry("BarUp", strategy.long)
if (close < open and open < close[1])
    strategy.entry("BarDn", strategy.short)
//plot(strategy.equity, title="equity", color=color.red, linewidth=2, style=plot.style_areabr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a user input to set the direction.

```
dir = input.string("Long", "Direction", ["Long", "Short"])
```

Then use this as a condition for your buy and sell signals.

```
if (close > open and open > close[1]) and (dir == "Long")
    strategy.entry("BarUp", strategy.long)
if (close < open and open < close[1]) and (dir == "Short")
    strategy.entry("BarDn", strategy.short)
```